# How to transpose/pivot the rows data to different column based on the value in Spark Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, pivot-table, transpose

I have a dataframe like this:

person_id ar_id new_value

```
101       5     Y
102       6     N
103       7     Full Time
104       8     Training
```

When I am executing:

```
val ar_id = Seq("5","6","7","8")
df.groupBy("person_id").pivot("ar_id",ar_id).agg(expr("coalesce(first(new_value), \"null\")"))
```

The output I am getting is:

```
person_id       5       6       7       8
101             Y       null    null    null
102             null    N       null    null
103             null    null    Time    null
104             null    null    null    Trainer
```

But my requirement is to have each value a different column name say 5 is status, 6 is manager, 7 is availability and 8 is role. like below:

```
person_id   status  manager availability role
101         Y       null    null         null
102         null    N       null         null
103         null    null    Time         null
104         null    null    null         Trainer
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Is that the output expected or not? A little confusing.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rename columns 5,6,7,8 to status, manager, availability, role, you can do the following:

```scala
val renames = Map("5"->"status", "6"->"manager", "7"->"availability", "8"->"role")
val newDF = renames.foldLeft(df){case (d,(key,val)) => d.withColumnRenamed(key,val))
```

Answer (score 0):

> Spark 2.4.3

```
scala> var df= spark.createDataFrame(Seq((101,5,"Y"),(102,6,"N"),(103,7,"Full Time"),(104,8,"Training"))).toDF("person_id", "ar_id" ,"new_value")

scala> var df_v1  = df.groupBy("person_id").pivot($"ar_id").agg(expr("coalesce(first(new_value), \"null\")"))

scala> df_v1.show
+---------+----+----+---------+--------+
|person_id|   5|   6|        7|       8|
+---------+----+----+---------+--------+
|      101|   Y|null|     null|    null|
|      103|null|null|Full Time|    null|
|      102|null|   N|     null|    null|
|      104|null|null|     null|Training|
+---------+----+----+---------+--------+


1.create a Map for columns to be mapped 
scala> val lookup = Map("5" -> "status", "6" -> "manager","7" -> "availability","8" -> "role")
```

2.then use map function to rename the columns

```
scala> df_v1.select(df_v1.columns.map(c => col(c).as(lookup.getOrElse(c, c))): _*).show()
+---------+------+-------+------------+--------+
|person_id|status|manager|availability|    role|
+---------+------+-------+------------+--------+
|      101|     Y|   null|        null|    null|
|      103|  null|   null|   Full Time|    null|
|      102|  null|      N|        null|    null|
|      104|  null|   null|        null|Training|
+---------+------+-------+------------+--------+
```

Hope this helps you retrieve your desired output let me know if you have any question-related o same and if it solves your purpose don't forget to accept the answer.thanks, HAppy HAdoop